# barcode plugin for phonegap not working

Tags: android, cordova, barcode

Having trouble in integrating barcode reader plugin for phonegap.
app stops working as soon as scan function is called.

plugin added by this link:

https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeScanner

ERROR in LOG CAT -
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.acme.demo/com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25: Error inflating class com.google.zxing.client.android.ViewfinderView

thanks

Comment: Please post your `config.xml`. You are likely using an out of date plugin.

Comment: thanks  JesseMonroy650,
but its resolved now by moving project from android studio to eclipse.

Comment: You are likely to run into more issues. Here are a few docs that could help. [Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md)  and [Cordova/Phonegap the white-list system](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-whitelist-system.md) Best of Luck